# Nammu's permissionGranted() callback is not getting called

Tags: android, android-permissions, nammu

I use **[Nammu](https://github.com/tajchert/Nammu), for asking and granting permissions to user.**

I go this code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.equals(myButton)) {

            Nammu.init(getActivity());

            if (Nammu.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //Its ok, do stuff here...
            } else {
               //Asking for permission
               //Third parameter is *this* Fragment. So the callbacks should fire here, in this class instance. Which is a Fragment.
                Nammu.askForPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this);
            }
    }
```

And in the very same Fragment I have:

```
    @Override
    public void permissionGranted() {
        Log.i("perm_is_granted", "yes, granted");

    }

    @Override
    public void permissionRefused() {
        Log.i("perm_is_granted", "no, refused");
    }
```

The problem:

Those two callback functions **never getting called.**
What m I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you overriding the "onRequestPermissionsResult" method in activity?
https://github.com/tajchert/Nammu#easy-asking-for-permissions